# Why is .query undefined on my model in Sails JS console?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In sails console, I should be able to:

```
User.query("SELECT * FROM USER")
```

But I get `undefined is not a function`, meaning `.query` is undefined.

I've reinstalled/updated sails and waterline, as well as sails globally and I still get the same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Sails documentation indicates using:

```
{
  ...
   adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
  ...
}
```

But sails-postgresql is still using the older:

```
{
  ...
   module: 'sails-postgresql',
  ...
}
```

Once I changed that I started seeing queries come through the server and the `query` function became defined under the model I created.

Comment: Where are you seeing a reference to the older `module` property?  I don't see anything on the sails-postgresql readme, and the default `config/connections.js` file in a new Sails app only uses `adapter`.

Comment: I don't see it.  I just tried it and it started working.  I ran into that issue with the sails-db2 module and decided to try it and it worked.  The weird thing is that all my dependencies as well as my global sails are at the latest version.  I have an issue on the sails-postgresql github trying to get a real answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

How did you configured the model User? Which adapter is it using?

.query method is only allowed when using an SQL adapter.

Comment: I have 3 adapters, mongo, postgres and db2.  It happens with all of them.  I can use the regular ORM just fine.

Comment: Strange. It works with the adapter for pgsql and mysql. In the model did you set which adapter you want to use?

Comment: Yep.  I checked that as well.  I'm thinking it could be a permissions issue, but I can `psql -h localhost -d samedb -U sameuser -W` and select data manually just fine.  I'm just not sure if that's the same access method that sails-postgresql/waterline is using.

Comment: Post che configuration of the Model User

Answer (score 0):

First you should verify your conection

```
#model
    module.exports.connections = {
      localMysql: {
        adapter: 'sails-mysql',
        user: 'root',
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'someDbase'
      },
```

if you run for example

```
#EXAMPLE
    User.find().exec(function (error, res){
    console.log(res)
    });
```

this return all users, later If you don't run .exec(), your query will not execute.

here you need a callback:

```
#CONTROLLER
    User.query("SELECT * FROM USER", function(err, results) {
      if (err) 
         return res.serverError(err);
      return res.ok(results);
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, I know all the basics.  I was having a specific issue connecting to postgres.  I solved it though, thanks.

Comment: ok, you don't specify sails version and in current documentation say is adapter https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline

Answer (score 0):

If you using local.js to set env.

Check env name, it should be small letters.

EX:- environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

I got same issue my env name was 'Development', changed to 'development' and working fine.